# Build advice for Heavens Oracle (Pathfinder)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, feats, skills, oracle

I'm building a 1st level half-elf oracle, lame curse, [heavens](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/heavens) mystery for an upcoming game.  She will be living in a world where mixed-bloods are subject to negative discrimination.  My goal is to use her as a battlefield controller, as well as a negotiator outside combat.

Proposed starting stats:  St 8 Dx 12 Co 12 In 12 Wi 12 Ch 19 (with one more pt I can put anywhere except Charisma).

I am taking Extra Revelation as my first feat, giving me two starting Revelations.  I decided on Lure of the Heavens, and am debating between Coat of Many Stars and Moonlight Bridge for the second one, but I am open to other options if anyone has well-reasoned suggestions.

As a half-elf, I get the bonus feat "Skill Focus" which can line me up for [Eldritch Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage) if I choose to go that route.  I'm consisering the [Karmic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/karmic) bloodline, but I'm wondering if anyone has any advice or experience with [Eldritch Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage), or suggestions on which might be most useful?  ...or any suggestions on other Feats to consider that might effect my stat or skill choices at this point?

Thanks for any help you can give.  I'm new to this class, but I really think I'll enjoy her if I start her out right. :)

Tyr

Comment: I've updated my proposed starting stats and added a few helpful links.  (Many thanks to AceCalhoon for fixing my link embed issue.) :)  I'm still interested in any thoughts on Eldritch Heritage... pros and cons.  I know the low strength makes some options less functional, but I feel like it could be a useful Feat if I plan it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some helpful resources on Oracles that might be of use to others who find themselves on the path of the blessed and cursed.

[Channelling the Cosmos](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WdtrZCESRmVfljXY196wMrMLTnS8Uzk4DEk3oQdVZok/mobilebasic?pli=1) - by Sean FitzSimon - this is a Treantmonk-style analysis of the Oracle.  I don't agree with *all* his opinions, but I found a LOT of the insights to be very helpful.  There is a whole section on Eldritch Heritage and some thoughts on the merits of some potential bloodlines.

There is also a chatty but interesting bloodline discussion [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=238267).

I am still very interested in any thoughts about the pros and cons of the different bloodline paths.

Thanks!
-- Tyr

Answer (score 1):

From someone who has never played Pathfinder, but a fair share of D&d 3.5 :

First things first, I'd drop the 12 STR. 10 should largely be enough for a troller, I might even go all the way down to 8 (especially with your specific curse, thanks to which your load won't matter much). These points will be much better spent in INT (you never have too much skill points) and/or WIS (to negate the sens motive malus the 8 brings. A negotiator needs as much Sense Motive as he can get).

Comment: This is a good thought.  Right now, I'm working on evaluating my spell list for touch attacks that I might lose if I drop Str to 10 or less.  I'll also have to eliminate bloodline abilities with melee attacks (like claws) or touch attacks when choosing my Eldritch Heritage bloodline, too.

Comment: I considered the pros and cons of shifting points around, and I think you're right about the relative merits of the stats, especially considering the upside of my curse.  It does restrict my maximum load, and it will decrease my melee functionality, but I agree that int & wis will be more important in my case.  Will do either S8 D12 C12 I13 W12 Ch19 -OR- S10 D12 C12 I13 W10 Ch19.  I certainly want sense motive & will saves within reason :)